# Find largest number $N$

Tags: summation, upper-lower-bounds, telescopic-series

> Find the largest number $N$ such that:
>   $$\sum_{n=5}^{N}{\frac{1}{n(n-2)}}<\frac{1}{4}$$

This was a question I came across while looking over local competition papers. It doesn't seem to follow any arithmetic or geometric sequence which I first thought of when first reading the problem.

So, I'm at a loss. How do you solve this?

Comment: Partial fractions & telescope ?

Comment: **Hint:** It looks likely that you can utilize partial fractions here and find a pattern.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$
\frac1{n-2}-\frac1n=\frac2{n(n-2)}\;.
$$

Thus, if you collect the even terms and the odd terms, most of the summands cancel (this is called “telescoping”), only one term involving $N$ remains in each partial sum, and you can get a simple inequality for $N$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{n(n-2)}=\frac{1}{2 (n-2)}-\frac{1}{2 n}$$ which beautifully telescopes
$$S_n=\sum_{n=5}^{N}{\frac{1}{n(n-2)}}=-\frac{1}{2 N}-\frac{1}{2 (N-1)}+\frac{7}{24}=\frac{7 N^2-31 N+12}{24 (N-1) N}$$ Now, you face a quadratic equation in $N$; solve it and use $\lfloor N\rfloor$.